# TSQL -- quick way to get a count across all tables

Tags: t-sql, count, sql-server-2014, ssms-17

If database `d1` has tables `T1,T2,T3,T4` all with the field `"Date1"`.

What is the best way to get a count of all records across all tables with a date older than 3 days ago?

I know one could do unions, I assume there is no nifty syntax that would omit all tables [like a 'parent' object in C++].

Here best may mean more efficient, or just a pleasing syntax in T-SQL.

This is for SSMS 17.7.  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2)

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Per request, updated with 17.7 -- this is in "help-->about" for my product.  Microsoft used that on all their products for years, but now it's missing from some Microsoft products!

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) isn't a database, but it can connect to one (or many). If you were using SQL Server you could use `select @@Version;` to get the version of the database software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're interested in a parent object, that would be a view, then. You can reuse it for a variety of queries. Alternatively, add more columns if you need them:

```
CREATE VIEW parent AS
SELECT Date1 FROM t1 UNION ALL
SELECT Date1 FROM t2 UNION ALL
SELECT Date1 FROM t3 UNION ALL
SELECT Date1 FROM t4;
```

And now, that can be queried in the way you want

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parent WHERE Date1 <= DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the table names in advance, a simple query on union all will probably be the simplest way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
     SELECT Date1
     FROM T1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT Date1
     FROM T2
     SELECT Date1
     FROM T3
     SELECT Date1
     FROM T4
) As t
WHERE Date1 <= DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
```

If you don't know the table names in advance, you can use `information_schema.columns` to  build the union query dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Without UNION?

Since a `COUNT` without a `GROUP BY` returns 1 value, why not use `CROSS JOIN` for once?

```
SELECT 
 t1.Cnt AS [T1], 
 t2.Cnt AS [T2], 
 t3.Cnt AS [T3],
 t4.Cnt AS [T4],
 (t1.Cnt + t2.Cnt + t3.Cnt + t4.Cnt) AS [T1234]
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM T1 WHERE [Date1] < CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE)) AS t1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM T2 WHERE [Date1] < CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE)) AS t2
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM T3 WHERE [Date1] < CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE)) AS t3
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM T4 WHERE [Date1] < CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE)) AS t4
```

Or a `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT 
 t1.Cnt AS [T1], 
 t2.Cnt AS [T2], 
 t3.Cnt AS [T3],
 t4.Cnt AS [T4],
 (t1.Cnt + t2.Cnt + t3.Cnt + t4.Cnt) AS [T1234]
FROM (SELECT CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE) as Dt) d
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM T1 WHERE [Date1] < d.Dt) AS t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM T2 WHERE [Date1] < d.Dt) AS t2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM T3 WHERE [Date1] < d.Dt) AS t3
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM T4 WHERE [Date1] < d.Dt) AS t4
```

**Example snippet for Sql Server:**

```
declare @T1 table (id int primary key identity(1,1), [Date1] date);
declare @T2 table (id int primary key identity(1,1), [Date1] date);
declare @T3 table (id int primary key identity(1,1), [Date1] date);
declare @T4 table (id int primary key identity(1,1), [Date1] date);

insert into @T1 ([Date1]) values (getdate()-6),(getdate()-5),(getdate()-4),(getdate()-3),(getdate()-2),(getdate()-1),(getdate()-0);
insert into @T2 ([Date1]) select top 6 [Date1] from @T1 order by [Date1] desc;
insert into @T3 ([Date1]) select top 5 [Date1] from @T1 order by [Date1] desc;
insert into @T4 ([Date1]) select top 4 [Date1] from @T1 order by [Date1] desc;

SELECT 
 t1.Cnt AS [T1], 
 t2.Cnt AS [T2], 
 t3.Cnt AS [T3],
 t4.Cnt AS [T4],
 (t1.Cnt + t2.Cnt + t3.Cnt + t4.Cnt) AS [T1234]
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM @T1 WHERE [Date1] < CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE)) AS t1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM @T2 WHERE [Date1] < CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE)) AS t2
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM @T3 WHERE [Date1] < CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE)) AS t3
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM @T4 WHERE [Date1] < CAST(GetDate()-3 AS DATE)) AS t4
```

**Returns:**

```
T1  T2  T3  T4  T1234
3   2   1   0   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead create a view, you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression). It works like a view, but not persists on database. Please try it:

```
WITH CteDate( Date1 )
AS ( SELECT Date1 FROM t1 UNION ALL
     SELECT Date1 FROM t2 UNION ALL
     SELECT Date1 FROM t3 UNION ALL
     SELECT Date1 FROM t4
    )
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CteDate WHERE Date1 <= DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
```

It works for all SQL Server greater or equal then 2005.